# Synagogue of Satan in Revelation 3:9?

Tags: revelation

> Revelation 3:9
> I will make those who are of the **synagogue** of Satan, who claim to be **Jews** though they are **not**, but are liars--I will make them come and fall down at your feet and acknowledge that I have loved you.

Was this group of people Jews or Gentiles genetically?

Comment: See John 8:30-59.

Answer (score 1):

In my IVP commentary, I note: The language around the synagogue of Satan is a very close parallel with the language around the same phrase in the message to Smyrna (2:9), and these are the only two mentions of Jews. It is striking that in the two cities that receive no rebuke, both are living in tension with the Jewish community, indicating not their enmity so much as their closeness. If Jesus is the Jewish messiah, coming first to the Jewish people and only secondarily to Gentiles (as reflected in much of Paul’s missionary activity in which he goes to the synagogue first; Acts 14:1), then faithful proclamation will lead to disagreement with those Jews who do not recognize his claims.

We also need to note that this word is one of reassurance to Jesus’ followers, and not an invitation to take action; it is Jesus himself who will vindicate them, and they are invited to leave that to him (compare Paul’s teaching on how we treat our enemies – blessing them and leaving God to judge; Rom. 12:20). Such language can never offer a foundation for anti-Jewish thought or action, not least because the assembly in Philadelphia will have included Jewish followers of Jesus. Their vindication lies less in what they have done and more in what God has done – he has loved them and given the life of his Son for them.

The idea of 'those who are Jews, but are not' is based on the same idea of Paul in Romans 2.28–29: 'A person is not a Jew who is one only outwardly, nor is circumcision merely outward and physical.  29 No, a person is a Jew who is one inwardly; and circumcision is circumcision of the heart, by the Spirit, not by the written code.'

Answer (score 0):

synagogue.
συναγωγῆς (synagōgēs).
Noun - Genitive Feminine Singular.
Strong's Greek 4864: From sunago; an assemblage of persons; specially, a Jewish 'synagogue'; by analogy, a Christian church

Revelation 3:7
"To the angel of the church in Philadelphia write: These are the words of him who is holy and true, who holds the key of David. What he opens no one can shut, and what he shuts no one can open.

1577. ekklésia ►.
      Strong's Concordance.
      ekklésia: an assembly, a (religious) congregation.
      Original Word: ἐκκλησία, ας, ἡ.
      Part of Speech: Noun, Feminine.
      Transliteration: ekklésia.
      Phonetic Spelling: (ek-klay-see'-ah).
      Definition: an assembly, a (religious) congregation.
      Usage: an assembly, congregation, church; the Church, the whole body of Christian believers.

The synagogue members were circumcised genetic Jews who refused to recognize the Messiah.  they were not true Jews in the Christian sense. the church in Philadelphia were true Jews according to Jesus. It is making a point between a synagogue and a church. The church had both Jewish and gentile members.

Answer (score 0):

It's people in the new covenant era that use the old covenant definition of the word Jew, and claim that puts them in covenant with the God of Abraham, Moses, etc without a belief in Jesus

Romans 2:28-29

> <sup>**28**</sup> For no one is a Jew who is merely one outwardly, nor is circumcision outward and physical. <sup>**29**</sup> But a Jew is one inwardly, and circumcision is a matter of the heart, by the Spirit, not by the letter. His praise is not from man but from God.

The SOS might claim physical genealogy means something too. No one can prove descent from someone that lived 4000 years ago but even if they could

1 Timothy 1:4

> Neither give heed to fables and endless genealogies, which promote questions rather than godly edifying in the faith, so do!

It is not children of the flesh that are children of the promise but children of the spirit.

If you belong to Christ you are Abraham's seed, and heirs of the promise.

God destroyed physical Israel and killed a lot of physical Israelites in 70 AD because they were not spiritual Israel. He warned them all throughout the OT but they just kept sinning.

There are a lot of other verses in the NT that address that topic too.

Here is how the rabbis in the Talmud explain the covenant they believe they have

When God explained to Joshua the reason for the Jewish people’s defeat at the city of Ai, He said: “Israel has sinned” (Joshua 7:11). Rabbi Abba bar Zavda says: From here it may be inferred that even when the Jewish people have sinned, they are still called “Israel.” Rabbi Abba says: This is in accordance with the adage that people say: Even when a myrtle is found among thorns, its name is myrtle and people call it myrtle. Sanhedrin 44a Talmud (Rabbinic writings from 200-500 AD)

The long list of curses in Deuteronomy 28, and "They are not all Israel that are from Israel" says otherwise.

Mark 7:6-8

> <sup>**6**</sup> He replied, “Isaiah was right when he prophesied about you hypocrites; as it is written:
> “‘These people honor me with their lips,
> but their hearts are far from me.
> <sup>**7**</sup> They worship me in vain;
> their teachings are merely human rules.’
> <sup>**8**</sup> You have let go of the commands of God (the Torah of Moses) and are holding on to human traditions.”

The word Jew in the bible should be Judean in OT, and NT also. It means living in Judah or Judea. Or of the religion of the peoples from those regions eg a number of apostles were Judeans but lived in Galilee so in that context it means they followed the religions of the Judeans which was various forms of the law of Moses at the time.

Answer (score 0):

The term "Jews" commonly referred to all members of physical Israel, not only literal Jews (e.g. Paul wasn't a Jew but a Benjaminite, but was still part of what is called Judaism).
And "synagogue" referred to both the physical building and to the people that congregated there.

In the first century, most Christians were Jews, and all Christians worshipped and studied in synagogues (where the sacred scriptures were available for study).
It was only later that Christianity fully separated and ceased being a sect within Judaism.

Today, as spiritual Israel, God's people are called Christians, and their houses of worship are called churches.

In modern English usage,

- "*those who are of the synagogue of Satan, who claim to be Jews though they are not*"

would have been written as something like

- "*those who are of the church of Satan, who claim to be Christians though they are not*".

This passage in Revelation has nothing to do with what we today think of as Jews and synagogues.